# pgfplots extra y tick formatting

Tags: pgfplots

In the MWE below I'd like to know to format the drawing such that

1. the extra y tick is formatted with two decimals, but the rest with just one decimal
2. <strike>Why doesn't it print zero? Zero should not be magenta</strike> (that was because of `axis lines=center`)

Here is the MWE, note that the stuff added to the extra y tick does nothing

```
\RequirePackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmax=1.1,xmin=0,
    ymax=1.1,ymin=0,
    xtick={0,0.5,1},
    ytick={0,0.5,1},
    axis lines=center,
    tick label style={
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
      fixed,
      fixed zerofill,
      precision=1,
    },
    extra y tick style={
      magenta,
      major tick style={
        magenta,
      },
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
      fixed,
      fixed zerofill,
      precision=2,
    },
    extra y ticks={0.87},
    ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You have to use the `tick label style` inside `extra y tick style`.
2. Add `hide obscured x ticks=false` and `hide obscured y ticks=false` to get the zeros printed. If this options are true (that is default) ticks will be hidden if the could be behind other axis lines.

[image]

Code:

```
\RequirePackage[svgnames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmax=1.1,xmin=0,
    ymax=1.1,ymin=0,
    xtick={0,0.5,1},
    ytick={0,0.5,1},
    axis lines=center,
    tick label style={
      /pgf/number format/.cd,
      fixed,
      precision=1,
    },
    extra y tick style={
      magenta,
      major tick style={
        magenta,
      },
      tick label style={% <- added
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
        fixed,
        precision=2,
      }% <- added
    },
    extra y ticks={0.87},
    hide obscured x ticks=false,% <- added
    hide obscured y ticks=false% <- added
    ]
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```